# form post returns text

Tags: php, post

form.html

```
            <form name="input" action="process.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter Your Name">                   
                <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Enter A Message">
                <br>
                <input class="shout-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Shout It Out">
            </form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
include "database.php";
echo var_dump($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);

    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['message']);


    //SET TIMEZONE
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $time = date('h:i:s a',time());

    if (!isset($user) || $user == "" || !isset($message) || $message == "") {
        echo "bad";
    } else {
        echo "good";
    }
}
?>
```

For some reason `$_POST` gives me text variable:

```
array(3) { ["text"]=> string(5) "david" ["message"]=> string(27) "adasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasd" ["submit"]=> string(12) "Shout It Out" }
```

> Notice: Undefined index: user in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\shoutit\process.php on line 6
>   bad

Comment: Try restarting XAMPP, or clear your browsers cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you've retyped form.html correctly on SO and there is an error in you actual code (mainly calling the name field text), or you had it like this, then fixed it and the your browser is caching the old version.

Easy way to check, in your browser view source on the form and check the form name.
Clear your cache and try again.